# Cannot embed third party url in lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

I tried to embed third party url in my lightning component , but unable to do so . Might be due to locker service ?Please check below code

```
<aura:component controller="Powerbilightning"  implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >


    <aura:attribute name="refreshToken" type="String" default="default value" />
    <aura:attribute name="validateResult" type="String" default="default value" />
    <aura:attribute name="selectedReport" type="String" default="**********" />
    <aura:attribute name="groupId" type="String" default="*************" />
    <ltng:require styles="" scripts="{!$Resource.PBIJS}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
        <Center>


            <a href="https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=reportId=***************&groupid=**********" class="uiOutputURL">PowerBi</a>




        </Center> 
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Might be due to locker service ? what makes you think so? have you tried debugging your single line of "code"? why have you implemented your component in soooo many interfaces?

Comment: ya gill , i am able embed url with visualforce page but i dont have much knowledge about  lightning, rather than criticizing, i will really appreciate if you could help me .

Comment: "I don't have much knowledge about lightning", I had pointed out learning material and links in the past post you deleted. you haven't included any debug info in your post, how do you expect us to help you? this is an exact copy of your other post, except that you have added a few attributes and script references. As is, your post is most likely to be closed as an Exact duplicate. cant help you if you cant help yourself. Start by learning the basics, update your post with relevant info and context and maybe someone will be able to help. Thanks

Comment: Totally agree with glls, this community and members have been welcoming and courteous to every other member. When you post random code with the random first thought that comes to your head, and also delete comments and repost the same question differently you should expect to get schooled !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locker Service is primarily concerned with security restrictions, such as importing unsafe scripts and preventing scripts from accessing unauthorized resources. It does **not** prevent simple anchors from working as they should (e.g. to redirect the browser to a new page), unless that anchor attempts to run a script, in which case it will be blocked if it attempts to directly call JavaScript.

Based on your previous question, plus this question, it's apparent that you've managed to mangle your URL in various ways. URLs *should not* contain random white space, and should conform to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), which your URL currently fails to do.

```
https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=reportId=***************&groupid=**********
```

Note that when I copy-paste this in to my browser, it assumes that you meant to write:

```
https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=reportId%3D***************&groupid=**********
```

That means that the remote server will interpret this as:

```
Parameter Name      Parameter Value
reportId            reportId=*****....
groupid             *****...
```

Which is *probably* not going to be accepted by the server you're making the request from. In addition, if your server doesn't allow unauthenticated access, you might end up not being able to access the resource without logging in first.

Either way, you need to make sure you have no random white space, and that your URL has the query string written correctly. Please make sure you have *exactly* copied the URL and not modified it in any way.